# C# Threads issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, picturebox

I want to do a simple thing.

I have a secondary thread listening to a usb reader, when the reader "reads" something, the thread fires an event. And that event starts a timer, but the timer does not work, I'm sure it is because about the threads.

Also, the timer must change some images in the form so this must be done in the main thread.

I hope I'm clear.

```
private void listenReader()
    {
        while (whileState)
        {

                if (readsSomething)
                {
                    evt.OnSomeEvent();
                    break;
                }

        }
    }

    private void eventStartsThisMethot(){
        //do a lot of things and start the timer
        }

    private void counter(){
        pictureBox.Image = Resources._5;
    //the timer ticks this methot
    }
```

So, listen reader need to be on separate thread for obvious reasons, but the second method must be done from the main thread, so I use an event, but if you have another idea.

Thanks

Comment: So if that thread fires an event that starts a timer, who exactly is listening to this timer? Also, which timer class are you using?

Comment: Xavier, it will be very difficult to get any meaningful answers without posting a code sample that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: `I hope Im clear :S` I am afraid you are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you added the [picturebox] tag, we can assume this is Windows Forms (Winforms). The event handler for your reader thread will execute on the reader thread and you need to execute code (in response to the event) on the UI thread.

You can use your Form's `BeginInvoke` method to execute arbitrary code on the UI thread

```
private void ProcessMessageOnUIThread(YourMessageType msg)
{
    // Process here
}

private void ReaderThreadEventHandler(YourMessageType msg)
{
    // Invoke the UI thread to process the message
    BeginInvoke(new Action(ProcessMessageOnUIThread), msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The counter method can check if the current thread can update the picture box, and if not, it can pass execution to the thread that can like this:

```
private void Counter()
{
    if (pictureBox.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Action action = Counter;
        pictureBox.Invoke(action);
        return;
    }

    pictureBox.Image = Resources._5;
}
```

I also recommend you use Pascal case for your method names - this is pretty standard. [Capitalization Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx)